# Consume stackexchange Api using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want consume StackExchange API in my ASP.Net application.

I made the model, the controller and the view but it is not working.
It keeps giving me the followng error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TaskTrial2.Models.question]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

**Model**

```
public class question
{
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public owner owner { get; set; }
    public bool is_answered { get; set; }
    public long view_count { get; set; }
    public string last_activity_date { get; set; }
    public long score { get; set; }
    public long answer_count { get; set; }
    public string creation_date { get; set; }
    public string question_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }




}
public class owner {
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string reputation { get; set; }
    public string user_type  { get; set; }
    public string profile_image { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<question> questions = null;

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        using (var Client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/");
            //HTTP GET
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/jason"));
            var response = Client.GetAsync("2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow");
            response.Wait();
            var result = response.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<question>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                questions = readTask.Result;


            }

        }

        return View(questions);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<TaskTrial2.Models.question>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }


<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
<tr>

    <th>link</th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.link
        </td>

    </tr>

}
```

Comment: It looks like the json you're receiving isn't an array it's an object

Comment: The error says you tried to load an array from a JSON string that *doesn't* contain an array. If you hit that URL you'll see the response is an object with an `items` property, not an array

Comment: The response is wrapped in an object. See here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper

Comment: Please post the response you get from the server.

Comment: visit the following url to see the response rom the server :   https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow

Comment: Can someone please show me exactly what am i doing wrong and show me the right way to do it.

Comment: @johnny5  i really need help on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to directly serialize to a list of questions when your request receive a wrapper for the questions first

```
public class StackResponseWrapper
{
    public List<Question> items { get; set;}
    public bool has_more {get; set; }
    public int quota_max { get; set; }
    public int quota_remaining { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't research the structure of the responses but my guess is this is a pagination wrapper which could be made generic e.g (`StackResponseWrapper<Question>`) but I'll let you investigate.

The key thing when deserializing json it to make sure that the structure matches what you're trying to deserialize to

Comment: Thanks alooooot . the problem was with my model , i used your solution + this link to fix my model :   http://json2csharp.com